# How I can show I list<string> or alternative in ComboBox ? (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox

Actually I have a work for my school in c# and I need to show a ComboBox list, but I don't like display of code :

```
combobox.Items.Add("example")
combobox.Items.Add("example2")
combobox.Items.Add("example3")
```

It's very long and I try to optimize with a List or string[] but I not have an idea how I can make.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF or something else?

Comment: I use WPF in school.

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the ComboBox's `ItemsSource` property, to anything that implements the `IEnumerable` interface:

```
combobox.ItemsSource = new string[] { "example1", "example2", "example3" };
```

For details see the documentation: [ItemsControl.ItemsSource Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource).